# solr length required

Tags: solr, solrj

I am trying to access solr server using solrJ

1. I deployed the solr in a subdomain search.xxx.com and trying to index some data using solrj client. But I am receiving "Length Required" in catalina.out of tomcat 7.
2. When I developed it, it worked fine in my local setup.
3. The querying is successful, even if 0 number of doc returned.
4. even if I dump this and go for data import handler(xml), how can I dynamically update docs.

below is the catalina.out error I am getting:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Length Required

Length Required

request: http://search.xxx.com/solr/product_mobile/update/javabin?wt=javabin&version=2
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:432)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:246)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:54)
    at com.xxx.product.solrclient.SolrConnection.indexListOfDocuments(SolrConnection.java:183)
    at com.xxx.product.solrclient.SolrOperations.reloadDataIntoSolrIndex(SolrOperations.java:169)
    at com.xxx.product.servlets.AjaxCallHandlerServlet.reloadSolrIndex(AjaxCallHandlerServlet.java:235)
    at com.xxx.product.servlets.AjaxCallHandlerServlet.doPost(AjaxCallHandlerServlet.java:140)
    at com.xxx.product.servlets.AjaxCallHandlerServlet.doGet(AjaxCallHandlerServlet.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at com.inspion.product.servlets.ProductFrontControllerServlet.doGet(ProductFrontControllerServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.inspion.product.filters.ProductRequestValidatorFilter.doFilter(ProductRequestValidatorFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? We have the same exception right now, I'm looking for the answer. Solr worked for us for a long time, but it was broken with last release. We can't find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a full answer (and I cant 'comment' yet in stackoverflow).

It seems your solrj request is not answered by solrservlet but an error page or something.  Is there a webserver infront of search.xxx.com?

You may want to start with the system out/error logs of tomcat server to get the server side exception.   That will help.

Comment: 1. there is apache http web server before tomcat, 2. search is successful, only indexing is problem, I can change the method to GET, but then data length will be limited 3. i am not getting sysout,syserr  so not getting full info, but from catalina log it seems request is reaching solr server.....Thanks for your help

Comment: I vaguely recall encountering this error when I added an empty documentList to the server.

Comment: I tried both single doc and collection of doc. both same issue....@user1452132... now I see some hope from your last comment. could you share some more info how you got rid of the issue..thanks

Comment: I think I started with posting xml docs out side my solrj client, and when that worked, made sure at least one valid doc was posted with solrj.  Sorry, I wish I remembered more..